# Can movie data from a movie strip in the VSE link to data in a texture?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

In one scene of my .blend file, I use a frame from a video file in a texture. In another scene, I have a movie strip in the VSE that uses the same video file. Since this is Blender, I assumed that I would be able to link the data for the movie strip from the data for the movie into the texture, but I cannot see a way to do this.

**What I really need is for one to be changed when the other is.** Right now my solution is a really ugly python function, but I'd rather it work like other objects/strips in Blender. **Is there a way to link the data used in strips in the VSE from other parts of Blender?**

Comment: The data blocks for VSE strips and textures are completely separate. Apart from paths there are a number of other metadata values that cannot be transported between scenes or uses. For example if you trim and place a video strip in the VSE you probably don't want those decisions to carry over onto your 3D object. So these properties are kept independent.  However the MCE Movie Clip can be used in VSE, Tracker and Compositor but sadly not the texture slots.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make a scene that renders or outputs the texture (eg. connect it to a composite output). Then in the sequencer instead of adding the video select the *scene* strip from the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (Add) menu.

[image: VSE: Add a scene strip menu]