# Render with openGL from the command line?

Tags: rendering, command-line, opengl

Is it possible to use the openGL [*quick render*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Vitals/Quick_render) for rendering from the command line?

e.g. something like `blender -b <file> -E opengl -f 1`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is possible, in a round-about way. Operator [`render.opengl()`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_68_2/bpy.ops.render.html#bpy.ops.render.opengl) needs OpenGL display context, i.e. Blender's window, to be opened. Hence, we can't do UI-less rendering using `-b` command switch. We'll need to do it through a script:

```
import bpy
import sys                      # read argument from sys.argv
from bpy.app.handlers import persistent

@persistent
def do_render_opengl(dummy):
    bpy.ops.render.opengl(animation=True, view_context=False)
    bpy.ops.wm.quit_blender()

bpy.app.handlers.load_post.append(do_render_opengl)
```

It is to be executed like this:

```
blender -P render_opengl.py <file>.blend
```

Executing [`wm.quit_blender()`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_68_2/bpy.ops.wm.html#bpy.ops.wm.quit_blender) is necessary, because otherwise Blender doesn't automatically close when render finishes. We also wrap the rendering code in [`load_post`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_68_2/bpy.app.handlers.html#bpy.app.handlers.load_post) handler, to make sure the right context is loaded up before rendering. This is especially important if the scene's name is non-default. Otherwise Blender creates new scene `Scene` and renders it, instead of the scene we want.

The script above is to render preview animation. To render preview image and specify frame range, modify it to read argument from `sys.argv` (I've written code that does it [before](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1104/185)) and assigning appropriate values to [`bpy.context.scene.frame_*`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_68_2/bpy.types.Scene.html#bpy.types.Scene.frame_current).

Comment: Thanks! this works. (though it is a little awkward with ui popping up..) Is there a way to get it to render with antialiasing?

Comment: @gandalf3: Ensure 3D View is set to camera view before saving, and change `view_context` in the script to `True`. I set it to `False` so it renders through active camera, irrespective of view settings, but it doesn't play well with antialiasing.

Comment: The reason you get the default _Scene_ without `load_post`, is due to you calling the script before loading the file. Changing the order of the arguments, works as expected.

Comment: @Aldrik: Cool! I haven't noticed that one.

Comment: @Adhi I'm getting some context error using your method when running bpy.ops.object.parent_clear(type='CLEAR_KEEP_TRANSFORM') or bpy.context.workspace.screens[0].areas Any idea how to fix that?