# Improve text only rendering time

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I need to render a small (30s), text only scene, in a very fast way. The result needs then to be added on top of a multilayer exr frameset, to produce the final video.
I'm using blender-internal, and having already disabled raytrace, textures, AO, etc... the question is: what can be done (maybe at code level) to reduce the rendering time as much as possible?

Many thanks,
Regards GLoureiro

Comment: Note, its not clear why this is really a problem. Is text rendering very slow?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have done some of things I would have already suggested.

- Use Blender-internal or OpenGL render.
- Reduce anti-aliasing samples.
- Use a shadeless material
- Don't use any lamps.
- Tweak text resolution (for fewer triangles)
- Experiment with tile size (larger tiles may give better performance)
- Lock the user interface while rendering.
- Render from the command line. (means you can't use OpenGL easily
  see  [Render with openGL from the command line?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2573/599) )
- Check which formats save to disk fastest *(PNG with low compression is quite good)*.

Comment: OpenGL is much faster doing this task, but from your answer its not usable via command-line, and its my case... is there any way to use it programmatically?

Comment: You can run blender from the command line, it can open a window, GL render, then quit. If you don't have a graphics card (physically no GPU or monitor, some servers are configured this way) the only way I found to use OpenGL from the command line is to use Linux/Unix with a dummy X11 server (xorg) and use Mesa's software OpenGL (which is still fast for previews). Setting `xorg-dummy-video` for the driver

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2573/599