# Run opengl render in background

Tags: python, rendering, add-on

I working on an addon and i need to run an opengl render by subprocess. When i run my script test, i've got this error:

```
RuntimeError: Error: Cannot use OpenGL render in background mode (no opengl context)
```

This is my command:

```
sub = subprocess.Popen([bpy.app.binary_path, blendfile, '-b', '--python', render_script])
```

Does it mean we can't do opengl render in Background ?

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't use OpenGL in the background. You shouldn't use the -b flag, and instead, close Blender in the end of your script using `bpy.ops.wm.quit_blender()`.

[Blender creates screenshot using python script but not when running in background](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82936/blender-creates-screenshot-using-python-script-but-not-when-running-in-backgroun)

[Render with openGL from the command line?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/render-with-opengl-from-the-command-line)

Comment: Please don't use 'here' as a link text; it makes it hard to understand what is being linked to. More info at [W3C QA Tips: Don't use "click here" as link text](https://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/noClickHere).