# How to save viewport image when running Blender as Python module

Tags: python

I need to save viewport image while running Blender as Python module.This is required because I need real time updated ( only available on viewport )?

Does somebody now is it possible?

Comment: Same deal as https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45548/run-opengl-render-in-background

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can save images rendered from the viewport.

```
# Set save path
sce = bpy.context.scene.name
bpy.data.scenes[sce].render.filepath = "./image.png"

# Go into camera-view (optional)
for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        area.spaces[0].region_3d.view_perspective = 'CAMERA'
        break

# Render image through viewport
bpy.ops.render.opengl(write_still=True)
```

[Here](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.render.html) are all the different python rendering commands.

A tip for finding out python commands: go into Blender, then Edit > Preferences > Interface tab > check Python Tooltips box. Then you can hover your cursor over any button and the python code command will display as well.

By the way: I am not sure what you mean by 'real-time updated'?

Comment: AFAIC this is wrong.  The OP is using `bpy` as a python module, in which case it is running without a UI (headless)  Same deal using background mode `blender -b`.  Trying to use `bpy.ops.render.opengl()` will result in the error `RuntimeError: Error: Cannot use OpenGL render in background mode (no opengl context)
`

Comment: If you run this code without the background mode, it will open Blender and it will work.

Comment: See Question: _"while running Blender as Python module"_