# Mapping an algorithm to an animation

Tags: animation, python

I have written an algorithm that can compute fingering of piano scores.

Now I would like to have a 3D animation of a pair of hands playing this score. Each finger is already assigned to a key.

How could I use blender api for this. If it is possible at all?

Comment: Can you elaborate some more. How do you envision this workflow to go? Should it be all automatic (maybe the best if you plan to animate long or many scores). Is it ok if there are some manual steps?

Comment: There should not be any manual steps. So basically, it should be able to operate command line. Input a musicXml with fingering information -> output animation

Comment: @dorien Have a look at the python [API reference](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.types.Armature.html?highlight=animation)

Comment: Seems to me this would be ideal for the game engine.

Comment: @dorien Had you any problems to adapt the script below?

Comment: I was looking for something more specific for piano fingerings. As it would require a lot of rules to make the hand move correctly. If I have time I might give it a show.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a very basic example of what you're trying to achieve:

A control file holds some data in the format
Frame-no obj_name,value of 'Key 1'
I have only created 2 shape keys (basic and 'Key 1') to test the script.

```
1 Finger1,1
1 Finger2,1
1 Finger3,1
1 Finger4,1
10 Finger1,.5
20 Finger2,.5
30 Finger3,.5
40 Finger4,.5
50 Finger1,1
```

The python script reads the control file and adds keyframes for each line

```
import bpy

filename='C:\\dev\\finger_shape.txt'

for line in open(filename):
    line=line.rstrip("\n")
    # Only append lines that have space in them.
    if line.find(" ") != -1 and line.find("#") == -1:
        # Split non comment lines of the format: Frame-no obj_name:value of 'Key 1'
        frame,obj_key= line.split(" ")
        obj,value=obj_key.split(",")        
        bpy.context.scene.frame_set( int( frame ))
        bpy.context.scene.objects.active = bpy.data.objects[ obj ]
        bpy.context.object.data.shape_keys.key_blocks['Key 1'].value = float(value)
        bpy.context.object.data.shape_keys.key_blocks['Key 1'].keyframe_insert('value')
```

Result:

[image]

Regarding you comments on automatise the rendering you might find these posts interesting:

- [Is there a way to batch render multiple scenes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/313/is-there-a-way-to-batch-render-multiple-scenes/315#315)
- [Blender rendering automation (build script)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1101/blender-rendering-automation-build-script/1104#1104)

Parsing XML is not blender related but you should find examaples on SO:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912434/how-do-i-parse-xml-in-python