# Manual voice syncing?

Tags: animation, audio

I wan't to animate based on an audio track by **manually** using key frames and shape keys. In the past I have used audio scrubbing. I would place my sound clip into the VSE and it would work perfectly.

But now, suddenly for a reason unknown to me it has stopped working as usual. Instead of just playing the sound for that frame, it plays the whole track whenever I click on the timeline.

**How can I revert it to its old behavior?**

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand the problems you have since last december. I also tried to create animations from a control-file therefore I share some thoughts on this topic.

### Pointers

- First step would be to identifiy the [phonems](http://animation.about.com/od/flashanimationtutorials/a/animationphonem.htm) in the audio stream used there is lip-syncing tool [Papagayo](http://www.lostmarble.com/papagayo/index.shtml)
- In this BA [thread](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?254015-Creating-a-reusable-set-of-phoneme-poses-to-form-a-sentence-or-phrases) someone used the Papagayo output as input for the script posted there, I it basically applies poses from a poselib.
  I was able to get it work for the latetest blender release.

### Answer

> My question is if anyone knows how i could animate to a voice without
>   automating it with the idea of shape keys for certain voice sounds.

- I created a script to read a control file with frame#, object and influence to automatically create an animation: [Mapping an algorithm to an animation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5358/mapping-an-algorithm-to-an-animation)
  It is very basic but easy to extend to use multiple shape-keys.