# How to automate rendering of the same object with different textures?

Tags: rendering

I know that a similar question [have been answered](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1101/blender-rendering-automation-build-script) a few years ago, but I really don't understand the answers or know how scripts works and where to put them.

I want to know if there's a *simple* way to automate the rendering process on the same OBJ but with different textures (.dds files)

I need to make rendered images of the same OBJ in the same angle but with 50 different textures, and save rendered images with different names (like: image1; image2; etc) and honestly I'm really lazy to do that without an automation.

I don't know if I'm clear, so I made a video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oBeKjvX3_uc&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36748/how-do-you-animate-image-texture-materials-in-blender-cycles-with-keyframes/36793#36793

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Name your texture files as a sequence if they aren't, like this:

```
0001
0002
0003
0004
....
```

In the material editor, choose **Image Sequence** instead of **Single Image** and choose all your textures. If you are using using the Node Wrangler addon, you can add them through the add menu, Texture >> Image Sequence.

[image: Node Tree]

Set the end frame to the number of texture you have, and render the scene as an animation and you will get your model with different texture for each frame.

Comment: I didn't know it was that simple ! Thank you so much, you really save my time !!

Comment: Thanks, really good methode, would it be hard to do something similar but for PBR materials (but some don't have specular texture for example) ?

Answer (score 0):

Well I can think of a simple way to do it (no scripting), although it may be a little tedious to set up.

Let's say you want 10 materials.

Duplicate your object 9 times in place.  Give each duplicate its own distinct material.

Set your timeline to 10 frames.

On Frame 1, keyframe animate object 1 as visible (viewport and rendered) and the other 9 objects as not visible.

On Frame 2, do the same so that only object 2 is visible.

Repeat for all 10 frames.

Now render your project as animation, outputting each frame as an image in your preferred format.

Every frame will be named differently and will have a version of your object with a different texture.

EDIT: Omar Ahmad's answer is better if your materials are identical except for the image texture used.

However, if your different materials differ in other ways (different shaders etc), this solution might be a better fit.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to respond me, I really appreciate ^^ ! 

But yes for my case, I think the answer of Omar is a bit simple and faster, but thank you ! I'm sure it will be usefull for other people :D