# Blender crashes when started from the command line

Tags: python, command-line

I'd like to run Blender from the command line (like [this](http://caretdashcaret.com/2015/05/19/how-to-run-blender-headless-from-the-command-line-without-the-gui/)) in Mac OS, but am running into an error which causes Blender to crash each time I run `./blender` (from within /Applications/Blender/blender.app/Contents/MacOS):

```
Jamies-MBP:MacOS Jamie$ ./blender
ndof: 3Dx driver not found
Read new prefs: /Users/Jamie/Library/Application Support/Blender/2.74/config/userpref.blend
found bundled python: /Applications/Blender/blender.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/2.74/python
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/__init__.py", line 123
    raise CodecRegistryError,\
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Illegal instruction: 4
```

The OS also reports that 'Blender quit unexpectedly.'

The error seems to suggest that Blender is looking for Python 2.7, but I thought Blender would always use its own copy of Python 3? If I run `which python` I get `/usr/bin/python`, and if I run `which python3` I get `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3`.

If I run `$PYTHONPATH` the output looks like this:

```
-bash: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg:
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip:
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7:
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin:
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac:
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages:
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python:
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk:
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old:
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload:
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC:
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages:
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL: No such file or directory
```

I'm not sure whether this is typical or not (there seems to be an No such file or directory error but I don't know if that's related).

What should I do to fix this or investigate this further? Do I need to add python3 to my `$PYTHONPATH`? [This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2079/1859) mentions other variables, such as `$BLENDER_SYSTEM_PYTHON` – do I need to change this?

Answer (score 2):

Well the solution for me was to unset my `$PYTHONPATH`, which was configured to create the output listed above by a line in my ~/.bash_profile file.

When started from the Terminal, Blender now still loads the bundled Python:

```
found bundled python: /Applications/Blender/blender.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/2.74/python
```

But Python is now able to load the modules it needs. I guess that having `$PYTHONPATH` set was preventing Blender's Python from being able to load required modules.

Comment: I had a similar problem, but Python 2.7 path wasn't in my PYTHONPATH , but in in my PATH environnement variable. Thank you for pointing me the right .. path :P

Answer (score 0):

This was one of the top answers for me when I had the same problem; here's what my issue was:

I made a **hard** link between my Blender download (which I put in `/opt/blender`) and my `/usr/local/bin` folder. With the **hard** link the executable isn't able to find the Python files it needs in its own subdirectory because it's looking for them in `/usr/local/bin` instead of where they're actually located, which is `/opt/blender/3.0/python`, etc.

First I had to remove the hard link:

`sudo rm /usr/local/bin/blender`

And then I had to remake it as a **symbolic** link:

`sudo ln -s /opt/blender/blender /usr/local/bin/blender`

The `-s` flag in the `ln` link command is what creates a symbolic link and it's the difference between the error OP gave and Blender starting correctly.

Pro tip, too: If you're getting Unity errors where `Blender could not be launched` after you've done this then you need to right-click the Assets folder in the Unity Editor and "Reimport All".

Comment: Check where your blender file is being invoked with `which blender`. The whole blender install shouldn't be at that path, which means that whatever result you get from that command should be the SYMOBLIC link. If you check it with `ls -l /path/you/were/given` and it doesn't show a link back to your Blender install then you need to do the steps above.