# How can I render a composition(s) from the command line?

Tags: rendering, animation, compositing-nodes, command-line

I've never used the python console before so I only know [these](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/render.html#animation) commands from the documentation that I've looked up. But I've read that it can be a lot faster than just pressing ctrl+F12 because it doesn't need the GUI.. or something. I looked in other places as well but my brain started to melt from this programming nightmare thing. I also have multiple scenes that needs rendering, so if I could do them one after another, it would be a plus. So if someone could show a command that let's me render my animation(s) in the compositor from the command line, it would be most appreciated!

Comment: To clarify You don't use the python console to run commands. You type  them into a command shell, or [terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal#Software) or whatever your OS calls it.

Comment: Well, yeah. As I said I know nothing about it :/

Comment: Yep, stphnl329 also linked this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is already a [previous question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1499/can-blend-files-be-queued-for-animation-rendering) about creating render queues.

The [Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/render.html#command-line-rendering) also has a section about command line rendering if there are any specific commands you need to add.

Comment: When I render from the command line, the compositor File Output nodes are ignored. Does the Manual address this?  EDIT: nevermind, the Manual lists `--python-expr`, which can be used as a workaround.