# Blender as a VSE - can I separate my editing into multiple scenes and render as single video?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I'm using blender just for the VSE functionality.  As such, I have created two scenes each with some movie clips.  I'm trying to render the output into a single movie using:

```
blender -b demo2016.blend \
        -S 01_Scene -s 1 -e 13 -a \
        -S 02_Scene -s 1753 -e 1760 -a
```

(From: [Is there a way to batch render multiple scenes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/313/is-there-a-way-to-batch-render-multiple-scenes))

In the properties window for each scene, the option 'Overwrite' is *not* ticked.

However, only the second scene is output to the final video.  Is this the correct approach?

Answer (score 2):

In the end, I solved this by creating a final Scene (which I called 'All_Scenes') and then adding the other Scenes as Scene strips in the VSE (Header menu: Add >> Scene).  In the scene properties, I had to configure the rendering to output as mp4.

In the Scene properties, I had to ensure the 'Use Sequence' property was ticked.

I could then render the scene with:

```
 blender -b demo2016.blend -S All_Scenes -a
```

Comment: so you still had to manually append each scene to All_Scenes?