# blender cannot be started from command line / wrong path in environment variables?

Tags: command-line

I am trying to run blender from the command line on windows and followed this instruction [Command line](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/258769/command-line-blender-not-found?noredirect=1#comment441455_258769). I have a problem setting up the path in System properties/environment Variables. I actually followed the instruction but Blender does not start. The error message says that blender is misspelled or cannot be found. I think the problem lies in the path. But I have located the blender.exe file and just copied the exact path. I appreciate your help.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What windows version? check this one https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm it says you have to restart you system. did you restart?

Comment: Just saying, in the console window the user's home directory seems to be *chris*, while in the dialogs it's *User2*. I would expect the same name here.

Comment: To track the problem: 1) close the edit dialog and open a new console to ensure that all changes take effect. 2) then check the environment variables by entering *set* in the console and hitting enter/return key. Check the *PATH* and the *USERNAME* variables. In the path list, there should be the blender directory. 3) select the blender path + hit enter to copy it, then change the folder in the console with *cd "<paste path here>"* incl. the quotes (") to check if the folder exists and you have access rights. 4) Try to start *blender.exe* there

Comment: @Blunder Strangely there is no blender in the path unter: Path=C:\Program Files ... 
Besides the other lines, it says:
Username=chris ... userprofile=C:\Users\chris ... hmm I also don't see any option to change user2 to chris in the dialog

Comment: Is *User 2* your admin user? The problem is that you changed the environment variables for *User 2* but the console window is started by user *chris* (different user context). My guess is that you're logged in as *chris* but when you open the system control Windows asks you for the login of a different (admin) user. It does this on my computer. The crazy thing is there are at least 3 system controls/configs dialogs in Win 10. >,<

Comment: Try this: Click the *Windows Start* button & type *Umgebungsvariablen* (for "environment variables"). This should show you the correct control panel and directly open the dialog as shown in the bottom left of your screenshot. The dialog should be called "Umgebungsvariablen" and below there should be *Umgebungsvariablen für chris* (and not *...für User 2* as in your screenshot). Change there the path and open a new console window. Then it should work.

Comment: @Blunder Man you are AMAZING! That was it!!! When typing "Umgebungsvariablen" ("environment variables") it showed me "environment variables FOR THIS ACCOUNT. Thank you so much, man! If you want to, you can suggest the solution and I give you the check mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you changed the environment variables for *User 2* but the console window is started by user *chris* (different user context). My guess is that you're logged in as *chris* but when you open the system control Windows asks you for the login of a different (admin) user.

You need to change the *PATH* variable for the current user.

Try this:

- Click the Windows Start button and type *Umgebungsvariablen für dieses Konto bearbeiten* (German Windows version). In the English version, this is called "*Edit environment variables for your account*".

[image: windows - edit environment variables]

This should show you the correct control panel and directly open the dialog as shown in the bottom left of your screenshot. The dialog should be called *Umgebungsvariablen* (*Environment Variables*) and below there should be *Umgebungsvariablen für chris* (and not ...*für User 2* as in your screenshot).

Change there the PATH variable and open a new console window. Then it should work.