# Is there a fast way to render an obj+mtl file to PNG

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, opengl

I'm using command line blendering an obj+mtl file to PNG [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/313/is-there-a-way-to-batch-render-multiple-scenes). However, it takes 2 seconds to render a scene.

Is there a faster way to do so? Because, I need to render hundreds of output with the same scene, different texture?

Generally, my task is to render hundred of output every time user put a new logo on a t-shirt model on web interface, so I need a quick rendering method.

Here is my updated blender file [.blend](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=51746) and [with_texture.blend](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=51747)

Follow @edna suggestion, I have turned off anti-aliasing. It still takes ~2s to render.

```
bpy.context.scene.render.use_antialiasing = False
```

Here is my output for rendering
[image]

Comment: Do you know where the time is being spent? E.g. how long to load obj, read texture from disc, actually render?

Comment: Hi @Sazerac, I use python to measure the time spent, and this line of code `bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)` takes the most

Answer (score 1):

We can't help you without knowing what it is in your scene that is taking the time. Two seconds is almost nothing, so presumably it is a very simple scene and rendered using the Eevee or Internal engine.

Simplest answer is to lower the resolution. Beyond that, I would suggest that this question would be better on BlenderArtists, where there is more room to discuss things like render settings and their impact on the final image.

Regardless, I suggest you post an example file here: [PasteAll.org](http://pasteall.org/blend/)

Comment: Hi @edna, I have attached the blender file to my question.

Comment: Okay, I've had a look, though the texture isn't packed into the file (go to File/External Data/Automatically then resave and upload) so I can't assess its impact. On my computer it renders in 1s, but that reduces to 0.3s if I turn off antialiasing under render settings, 0.2s if I also reduce the image size to 80%, 0.15s if I change the image size to 1080x1080 and move the camera closer so that the t-shirt is the same size as before. I reckon that is about the best you can do other than simplifying the mesh which I suspect would be of limited benefit relative to the extra work.

Comment: Hi @edna, I'm not sure if I miss some parts. I turned off anti-aliasing in blend file then resave. And, I run the script again, it took `Time: 00:01.72 (Saving: 00:00.25)`

Comment: I also found these tips [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8gSyEpt4-60)

Comment: Looking at your file, it is certainly the textures that take the time. If you turn off the bump and colour textures, render times drop by ~70%. All I can suggest is that you simplify what you are trying to do, so that you don't need Blender to calculate relatively complex bump/colour textures which have a fairly subtle effect anyway. Good luck with it!

Comment: @edna [blend-exchange](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/630/935) is preferred over pasteall.

Answer (score -2):

Have you heard to talk about E_cycle? It's 7% faster than the regular release but this build is only useful if you use multiple GPUs in your PC.

You can find it on Gumrod or on Blender market, but for a better result, you have to download the last Nvidia content creator driver that has excellent performance with the last RTX GPUs.

Comment: Could you explain what E_cycle is and how it helps the OP? Perhaps give a short description of what it does and the benefits. Also post some direct links to where we can find it

Comment: All you need to know is in the link https://gumroad.com/discover?query=E-Cycles%202.8x

Comment: [Links to answers are not an answer](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2382/what-is-wrong-about-answering-with-a-link/). Please include all relevant information here, and don't post it in the comments, edit it into your answer