# F Clone brush and a lot of other brushes aren't included in Blender 2.77a?

Tags: texturing, uv, sculpting, uv-image-editor

I went to use the F clone brush for the first time after viewing this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eQy5jn9dWrs) on texturing. However, Blender (v2.77a) only has one brush,called `TexDraw`.

I was wondering:

1. How can I get all the brushes that should be included, or
2. how can I create a F clone brush that works.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Okay I started a new blender project and went immediately into texture paint. Again,all the brushes aren't there !. Does anyone know of any settings that could be responsible for this?

I attached two screenshots to show you :

1. here you can see that the author of the tutorial is using blender 2.72 and he can use a lot of brushes :

[image]

2. Instead,I can use only the `TexDraw` brush on blender 2.77a :

[image]

Comment: the author of that tutorial probably created those brushes with different settings and saved them as default, or is probably using an addon that adds brush presets. do you want an answer on how to create custom brushes?

Comment: I need to know how to cres

Comment: Create the clone brush because i want to complete the tutorial. Thanks.

Comment: the clone brush is included by default and you can't really create it since it's a special brush. [see this answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1599/2816) and how to get around this problem

Comment: I have the F-clone brush in Blender 2.77 Release Candidate 2

Comment: Where is located ?

Comment: Can you make a screenshot ?

Comment: Oh yeah. I found the clone brush. I have clicked over the texdraw brush and 10 other brushes are appeared. Anyway,I think that the location of the brushes can be improved...its not intuitive to click over one brush to show all the other ones...