# How can I use a material from one blend file in another?

Tags: blend-files

I have two .blend files and each one has materials library. How can I have the both materials libraries in ONE .blend file?

Comment: See [How can I reuse existing materials, objects, etc from an existing .blend?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/81/12).

Comment: Please search around before asking as there is a good chance your question has been asked and answered already.