# How can I apply some material included in a node-pack library?

Tags: materials

I am new to Blender. How can I apply some material included in a [node-pack library](http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/70570)?

Answer (score 8):

Those are [*Node groups*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/shader_nodes/groups.html?#node-groups). Node groups are node setups can take input to give an output with which you can use in other nodes. (Think of it like making a new node of many nodes put together, similar to a *function* in computer programming.) This also allows you to create a node setup then use it in many places.

The collection of node groups you linked to is made up of [*Shader* nodes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/shader_nodes/index.html#shader-nodes) and [*Compositing* nodes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/compositing/index.html#node-types). The author of the collection you linked to also explains the function of each node group [here](https://bwide.wordpress.com/node-groups/bwide-nodepack-for-blender/).

## Adding a node group to your blendfile:

You can use them in your own file *Appending* them. You can do this by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>*> append*, then navigating to the blendfile with the nodegroups which you want to use:

[image]

Pick the type of data to append, in this case we want *Node groups* so pick *NodeTree*:

[image]

Select the node group you want to import into your file:

[image]

See [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/81/599) for more information on appending and linking.

You can now add this node group to your own node tree.

In the *Node editor*, press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>*> Add node > Group* and select the appended node group:

[image]

You now have a new "node" which you can use in your node tree the same way you would use any normal node:

[image]

In the case of this node group, it supplies a *Shader* output, however some node groups return a value or an image (or a vector, or even multiple different outputs).

## Editing node groups:

- You can edit the nodes in a node group by selecting it and pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>.
- You can edit, add and remove inputs and outputs of the node group in the *Properties region* (<kbd>N</kbd>):

[image]

- You can have node groups inside node groups, so to go to the parent group (the node tree in which the currently active group is located) press the [image: up] button on the header. (you can think of this behavior as a file tree with the base node editor as `root`)
- You can [ungroup](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/shader_nodes/groups.html?#ungroup) nodes by selecting the group node and pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>. This will place all the nodes in that node group in the current node tree. (I.e. the currently open group or the base node editor)

## Other things to note:

The way node groups look and function [changed a lot in 2.67](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.67/Node_Editor#Group_Interface). See the [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.67/Node_Editor#Group_Interface) for a full description of the changes