# What is the fastest and easiest way to add a vignette in the compositer for Cycles?

Tags: node-editor, workflow, compositing-nodes

Poking around to find an easy vignette effect, I constantly run into seemingly unnecessary node setups. Six or seven nodes to add a vignette? An apparently really simple effect, this seems a bit much.

For simplicity, it just has to be circular (or oblong since 16:9) vignette. Doesn't need to have fancy options, just needs to work and be simple.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I usually do something like this:

[image]

It doesn't take too long to setup (three nodes), and it's provides a high degree of control:

- The aspect (or even rotation) can be controlled via the settings of the Ellipse Mask* node.
- The softness can be controlled with the *Blur* node
- The amount of influence can be controlled via the mix node factor.

## For a more automated solution

You could try something like this (click for full size):

[image]

This can be [grouped into a single node (and included in your startup file)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7826/599) with very simple controls:

[image]

Comment: I like to create node groups for things like this and add them to the startup blend (with fake users of course).

Comment: Nobody should use a fish eye lens when doing beauty shots of a monkey!

Comment: Perfect answer,

Comment: I'd like to add a very late thanks for this answer. It was just what I wanted.

Comment: Thank you but boy do I hate the math/add/mix nodes in Blender and the systems inability to search for the potential node names so looking at screenshots can just be enough. Anyways. "MULTIPLY" is Add/Color/MIX - see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81097/multiply-and-add-functions-in-node-editor/81099