# Multiply and Add functions in Node editor

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

How do I bring up the *Multiply* and *Add* functions in the *Node Editor*?

Can't find them when I do <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> or click *Add* at bottom menu.

Comment: They aren't dedicated nodes. They are "math" or "mix RGB" nodes with the mode set to "multiply" or "add". Was this what you were looking for? If not, please clarify in the original post.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**For Math:** <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> *Add > Converter* > *Math* and switch math function what you need.

**For Colors:** <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> *Add > Color* > *Mix** and switch blend mode

For greyscale images doesn't matter if you use math, or color - result is the same

*Mix used to to be called "Mix RGB"

Answer (score 2):

Vector: <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> *Add > Converter > Vector Math* and switch math function