# How to add custom nodes as a Blender standard

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, customization

So there's this website called Chocofur.com and the people behind it have created a custom node setup for cycles, that you can use to make basic shaders easily.

So I have downloaded their nodes from their website. The .zip file contained a .blend file which when opened only contained a single plane mesh with  a single material was assigned to it. Sure enough this "material" was simply all their custom nodes disconnected one after the other, some of them which you can see here:

[image]

Now the part where I actually make these nodes a part of Blender is where I get lost, how can I do this? I know it's something like making a group... but how do I use this feature?

Comment: technically these aren't custom nodes are they? just Node Groups?

Comment: As I've come to realize, yes they are. I thought Chocofur had made nodes from scratch uzing python or something like that (noob here)