# problems with appending a node group

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, customization, groups, append

I have asked how I can make a node group a part of the blender star-up file, which turned out was already answered **[here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7826/can-i-make-a-custom-node-from-a-group-and-have-that-available-in-other-projects)**

But the thing is I'm getting lost between step 4 and 5 of this answer. On step for it says: "Press Shift F1 to Append. Navigate inside the file with the node group, select NodeTree and then select the node group." and then on step 5 it says: "Add the node group (Shift A> Groups > Group) and press the F icon on the node to save the data block even if it has no users"

[image]

So am I supposed to actually append the node group or what? If I do that, where do I use the command Shift A > Groups > Group? Cuz' it sure won't work with the mouse pointer hovering above the 3D viewport, and neither does it work over the node editor window ...

So does anyone have an answer for me? Thanks for reading!