# Inconsistent color on rendered image

Tags: rendering

[image]

Clearly because of lightning but not sure what is the best way to fix this. Suggestions?

Edit:
The problem is with area in the red. The color is really inconsistent (Looks like clouds?). Lightning source would fix this but how would i achieve this naturally. Or its not achievable?

Material on walls, roof and cabinets are just normal diffuse. Tried to add more light bounces but that didn't help.

Comment: Hi. Please add more information to your question about what the problem with the image is and what the expected result is. You can add more information by using the [edit] link below your question.

Comment: Those clouds seem to be part of the material. Please add more information, this is not a "guess-what-I-did" kind of site. The best way to get help is if you provide a detailed description of the scene.

Comment: Its just a normal diffuse material. The "clouds" are not in the material.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have the De-noising filter on?  If so you might consider increasing the radius.  See this answer also: [How to reduce noise in really dark scene](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84322/how-to-reduce-noise-in-really-dark-scene/84326#84326)

[image]
[image]

Comment: You handsome beast! Thanks for this info. Really helped alot.