# Cycles spotlight creates fireflies on glass and glossy materials

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, shaders

Its about spot light lamps in combination with Cycles Glossy and Glas Shaders. In this post i only make use of unchanged shaders "Glossy BSDF" and "Glass BSDF" from cycles.

The blend file is here: http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=47499

And what i am trying to do is a simple Cycles setup using a camera, a flat cube and a spot light:

[image]

- The Spotlight has Strength 300 with a spot shape size of 20 degree
- The cube material uses Glass BSDF (Beckmann) with roughness 0.1 and IOR 1.45
- The camera looks straight downwards
- All items are aligned on the Z axis

This is the render result with 128 samples after about 15 seconds:

[image]

Now i want to get rid of the fireflies. I followed the recommendation to use more samples. I increased the number of samples from 128 to 1024 which created this image:
[image]

The downside here is that now the image renders in 2 minutes and actually the spot is not so much "spotty" but more "cloudy"

In the next experiment i increased the spot Strength from 300 to 1000 and now the flies are back:
[image]

Someone told me that increasing the lamp size will fix it. So i increased the lamp size from 0.2 to 1.0 and the flies are gone but the spot is again cloudy.

[image]

Ok, lets make a break here. Actually i am not even interested in the reflection on the glas surface (for now). I rather want to get the spot light passing the glass and travel further down to another flat cube that uses a glossy material (a mirror actually).

I change the setup a bit as follows:

[image]

So i now expect to see the reflection of the light spot on the lower plane, and indeed the spot is there, on the left side i see the reflection from the glas and on the right side i see the reflection from the lower plane (the mirror:

[image]

but ... fireflies are back :( Now i need some help out of this :) thanks for any hint!

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86635/will-increasing-samples-reduce-fireflies

Comment: please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to upload files. Links in pasteall.org have a limited time. Once the link is gone no one will have access to your file, making the question less useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [denoise feature in 2.79.](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.79/Cycles)

Using the default denoise settings with your file at 1024 samples (and 100% resolution):

[image]

A different option without denoising is to modify the default glass shader (see :[How to illuminate the darkness inside glass objects in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-to-illuminate-the-darkness-inside-glass-objects-in-cycles)).

(1024 samples at 100% resolution)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for all the information! this helped me to get much better results. I actually ended up with doing a combination of settings in the blender render panel, using the denoiser and creating a Glas material that works equally well for spotlight lamps and for area lamps and supports fresnel also in a convenient way :) Actually i merged a few proposals for glass materials in a way that suits my needs in this project. I now only need 128 samples to get good results.

Comment: @GaiaClary please write an answer detailing what you did. Other users with similar questions might find it useful.