# white pixels on a glossy/glass-shader

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv

I made a house in blender v.2.77 and I textured the windows with a glossy and glass shader. After I rendered the image there were white pixels on the windows. My samples are on 200. How can I get these pixels away ? (sry,I could not add any pictures)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1703/how-to-reduce-fireflies-in-cycles

Comment: Fireflies? Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/88310/cycles-spotlight-creates-fireflies-on-glass-and-glossy-materials

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86635/will-increasing-samples-reduce-fireflies