# I always get some noise in my images made with cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, lighting, noise-reduction

[image: this is just a kitchen]

There are also another problems with this image, but the noise I get in all my renders, I don't know how to solve this, could you help me. My renders also takes too long to render, even if it is a simple scene, I have here a i7 2.5Gh, a NVidia GeForce 940M 4GB dedicated and 8GB RAM, could you help in those questions please?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's impossible to help without seeing your actual settings.

Comment: It looks like you mainly got fireflies. If you can, try to enlarge your lamp. use area-lamps instead of point lamps. Also try to reduce your reflections. finally for render-time: if you can, skip caustics. try reducing the amount of light-bounces (4-5 usually is enough. You probably don't need 12). also: please post your settings

Comment: really that looks pretty clear. Try turning on denoising to eradicate the last bit of the noise.

Comment: The very short answer is you need a lot more samples. There are, however, other thricks to minimize fireflies and noise in general. Please read trough the following links: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4980/how-to-avoid-noisy-renders-in-cycles and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/88310/cycles-spotlight-creates-fireflies-on-glass-and-glossy-materials/88314#88314 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40040/fireflies-noise-on-glossy-material/40142#40142 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86635/will-increasing-samples-reduce-fireflies