# Why is there still so much noise?

Tags: 3d-view, lighting, noise-reduction

I added a portal to the the window and put the size to 9.353, and also rendered the samples at 2000 and there is still noise. do I need to portals for this?

[image]

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information. We don't know how you set up your project or your textures or render settings. Most fireflies can be dealt with by using clamp indirect, using larger light sources and using the denoiser. See :  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96101/problems-with-denoising-in-rendering/97491#97491 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/88310/cycles-spotlight-creates-fireflies-on-glass-and-glossy-materials/88314#88314

Comment: Also worth reading: [Will increasing samples reduce fireflies?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86635/will-increasing-samples-reduce-fireflies)