# How to get rid of white particles?

Tags: animation, eevee-render-engine

So, I'm making a Lego Animation and for some reason every time I enter Viewport Shading, there are like these white particles on the Lego Models. And I have a giant green cube in the background and that object does not have white particles. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks

(BTW I'm using Eevee to render it)

[image]
There is tons of these little white dots or particles on the Lego Model

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: are you using volume or glass shaders? if so check these out: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1703/how-to-reduce-fireflies-in-cycles
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/88310/cycles-spotlight-creates-fireflies-on-glass-and-glossy-materials

Comment: @ShantanuAryan I am using none of those