# How to reduce noise

Tags: depth-of-field, noise-reduction

[enter link description here](http://www.picshare.ru/view/8862003/)

after enabling depth of field i faced with problem of noise. Metal objets especially looks very bad. How to fix it?

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and use the tools from this site to upload images so that they appear as part of your question. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: Read also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86635/will-increasing-samples-reduce-fireflies and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1703/how-to-reduce-fireflies-in-cycles

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way is to turn on the Denoiser tool, but there are tons of other ways.
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/optimizations/reducing_noise.html