# Black artifacts on white posts but no doubles to remove

Tags: artifacts

As you watch the video, the first visible white post is 
pure white. But the others that are seen next have black speckles. I have tried to remove all doubles but there weren't any to remove.

https://vimeo.com/345115243

So much is riding on me getting this video finished. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks so much for your time!

Comment: With no detail whatsoever provided, how are people supposed to know the answer to this issue? Please try explaining your situation, what render engine you use, what version, post a .blend sample with reproducible problem or at least screenshots of your render settings. Is denoising used?

Comment: I posted a video of the problem which says a lot. The version is 2.79b using cycles render. Denoising is used.

Comment: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this

Comment: Read: [How to properly denoise renderings](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98510/how-to-properly-denoise-renderings/98535#98535) and [why do I have a large black and white artifact on the rendered image](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134626/why-do-i-have-a-large-white-artefact-on-the-rendered-image/134646#134646)