# How do i remove noise?

Tags: noise-reduction

I tried to make this scene from blender guro tutorial, but i got problem in my lamp which is to noisy. Is there a solution without increasing my samples render? 
Im beginner for this stuff.

[image]

Comment: BlenderGuru has made an article on this topic, "7 Ways to Get Rid of Fireflies Once and For All": https://www.blenderguru.com/articles/7-ways-get-rid-fireflies

Comment: Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84322/how-to-reduce-noise-in-really-dark-scene

Answer (score 1):

Use the denoising feature in Blender 2.79.
The noise might be caused by a glass material in your scene so I recommend deleting the object with the glass shader.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, now i fix the problem.