# Please let me know where to find these materials in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, add-on

[image: Where can i get these options in cycles?]

Hi Guys, I stumbled upon a file from this link [Here](https://www.youtube.com/redirect?event=video_description&v=AcmMUkk_Tb8&redir_token=5nlR8bTJZQJyzoSgi5arpWx7PJN8MTUwNjkyNjk4M0AxNTA2ODQwNTgz&q=http%3A%2F%2Fftp.mantissa.xyz%2Fresources%2Fother%2Fmantissa_rgs.zip)

How do i enable this menu through addons? I couldnt find it anywhere online :/

I need these effects on my own files.

Comment: Those are just custom node groups either created or appended/linked from another file. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7826/can-i-make-a-custom-node-from-a-group-and-have-that-available-in-other-projects for info

Comment: I see! Thanks, but it would be nice to know where its from tho. those are actually some nice effects to use!

Comment: They can be from anywhere but it's likely from the blend file you downloaded from somewhere. Node groups can be linked or appended from other blend files only