# Is it possible to get the output of a different material available as a node?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, groups

I'm building a model of a piece of swampland, and I'm hoping to use a material-blending technique I know from Unity to handle its appearance. It involves lerping between multiple other materials using RGBA values.

This would be particularly easy if I could simply reference another material, as it would exist under the given conditions, as a node; and receive its color and other properties as pins. However, I've seen nothing like this, and as of the moment, the best I can do is manually copy the node map of my target material to the current node map, and in the best case make it a node group.

This feels terribly inefficient to me!

Am I overlooking an elephant in the room?

Comment: Shader Mix node will do what you want, together with node groups

Comment: But I would, effectively, still have to copy the nodes from one material to another?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I make a custom node from a group and have that available in other projects?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7826/can-i-make-a-custom-node-from-a-group-and-have-that-available-in-other-projects)