# What kind of node is this?

Tags: node-editor

What kind of node is this?

[image]

<sub>Image from this [blog post](http://nixart.wordpress.com/2012/05/22/blender-cycles-toon-material-node-setup-update/)</sub>

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3455/599

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nodes can be combined to a [Node Group](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Composite_Nodes/Node_Groups), the parameters you listed are part of a *Group Input* in the old (pre 2.67) style [*Group Interface*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.67/Node_Editor).

Each important in and output of a group of nodes can be wired to the group in- and output nodes to make them accessible when the group is collapsed.

The new style looks like:

[image]

<sup>Single Node nonsense example</sup>

You can collapse the view of a node group using the up-arrow button from the menu header, and expand it by clicking the icon right to the nodes title.

Comment: You can also press Tab on the keyboard to expand and collapse the node group.

Answer (score 1):

The nodes are in a Node Group and are labeled. If you trace the wires from the Color, Shadow, and MidShadow names, you'll see that they are just changing the values of the Emmission, Emmission, and Math nodes respectively. The Normal node is under Add>Vector>Normal.