# Can someone explain the node shown in this screen capture?

Tags: node-editor, groups

I trying to recreate a material by looking at an image that appears to show "nested" nodes. I tried every stock node but was unable to produce this setup.
[image]

These two "nodes" are used as components in this one, in the section named "marble pattern":

[image]

Comment: These are called "[node groups](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/node_editor/nodes/groups.html)". Some related questions: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/10894/599, http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/32984/599, and http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3455/599