# Problem appending a Node Group in Blender 2.71

Tags: node-editor, append

I am currently having a problem while attempting to append a Node Group into a new file.

I think I have followed the steps correctly; I created the node configuration, selected all the nodes, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>, saved to nodes1.blend; Opened a new file, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, navigated to the Node Editor of nodes2.blend then pressed <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>>Group, select the the group from nodes1.blend ... And there is a problem: the appended node is nowhere to be found.

The funny thing, is that when I go to Outliner > Datablocks, I can see the Node Group has effectively being appended (see screenshot below)

[image: Screenshot of Group error]

But the Group is just not available in the Node Editor; Am I missing something? I used to do this all the time with other Blender versions; Has anything changed? Please help. .blend file on request.

Comment: Could you upload the .blend file containing the group?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3455/599

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution to the issue.
I was trying to add the node group in shader mode, and not in Composite mode, as I should be.
I thought I had set it to Composite, but I guess I hadn't. As soon as I changed to Composite mode in the Node Editor, everything worked as expected.