# Can you export compositor nodes?

Tags: node-editor, workflow, compositing-nodes

Not sure if this is a dumb question or not, but can you export compositor nodes to another project? I'd rather not recreate them on different projects for similar effects.

Comment: It's not a dumb question at all! :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Yes**.

By creating a [node group](http://blender.org/manual/composite_nodes/node_groups.html) (<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>) you can append (<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>) those node groups from other projects.

[image]

See [my answer here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3456/599) for more detail.

Comment: I do not seem to have a NodeTree folder within my other project, even though I do have use nodes checked for the compositor.

Comment: @douglasg14b Did you create a node group? You can only append nodes which are in a node group..

Answer (score 3):

Also beware that node group copies, between active scenes within a project, are not unique.  If you edit a value inside the node group of one scene then it will be charged in the other scenes. To fix it break open the local node group first.