# How to save a node setup for easy access in default scene

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

How can I save a node setup, such as procedural texture, so I can easily access it in my default scene. It would be a great help to not have to import or start fresh each time.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32984/is-there-a-way-to-save-composite-node-presets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's one use case for [Node Groups](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/node_editor/nodes/groups.html).

1. Select all relevant nodes and group them with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>. This way the created group is accessible within all material node trees, located in the *Add menu*: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Groups > Your Group Name*
2. Save your config as well as the created *node group* as part of your *Startup File* under *File > Defaults > Save Startup File*