# material with generic procedural maps?

Tags: materials, procedural

is there a way in blender to make a tree of procedural maps that can be used in several materials at the same time? and updated at once by changing their contents in the various materials that receive it? where they are linked to the map trees of the materials that receive it?

thanks

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32984/is-there-a-way-to-save-composite-node-presets/32985#32985

Comment: Voting to reopen because none of the answers in the supposed duplicate address the question asked here about global changes affecting every material.

Answer (score 6):

Sure create one material that has the tree you want.  Select the tree and make it a [*node group*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/controls/nodes/groups.html). (Shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>–<kbd>G</kbd>).  Hook some of the inputs to the group input and some of the outputs to the group output.  An expanded group might look like this silly example:

[image: Noise/Voronoi]

Once you've created such a group you can add it the same way you would add an individual node, by typing <kbd>Shift</kbd>–<kbd>A</kbd> and going to *Group* in the select menu and picking it by name.  I didn't change the name of the above group so it shows up as *Node Group* in the menu.  You should name your node groups so that you can tell what they do.

[image: Add menu showing "Node Group" as name]

In this silly example, any Material that uses the group can have a unique value for the *Noise Texture*'s *Scale* input, but if you change any other input, such as the *Voronoi Texture*'s *Scale* input, it changes it for every material that uses the group.

That is, Group Inputs are unique to a given use of the node group, but any internal setting is shared by every use.

Comment: and is it possible to turn this function off and on again for all materials with the same configuration? can i have a mixRGB node to connect external maps in the group?

Comment: yes.  for instance, pass a color in, use the node group to modify it, then use the mixRGB to select between the modified and unmodified version of the color.

Comment: can you be more clear? actually the above questions are two different questions.

Comment: Probably should ask another question.  I would need more screenshots to be more clear and I don't know how to add them to comments easily.

Comment: to change the values only in a material, just ungroup?Or is there another more efficient way?

Comment: Is it possible for a group to be used in several "files" and the settings to sync the same across all files?

Comment: to change the value for one material, ungroup, or make it a new group, open it and edit it.  To use in several files: Before v3, put a material in a separate file that has the group, and link that material into any file you want to use the group in.  Starting in v3, make it a material asset or do it the pre-v3 way

Comment: when applying a procedural map of an object to another object of smaller size, it is necessary to rescale the map. Is there anything I can do to not have to reconfigure the procedural map scale?