# Copying objects in 3D view along with nodes and other stuffs

Tags: node-editor

while I am trying to copy a object (with nodes) (e.g. cube) to another blend file. The object that I am trying to copy was modified with nodes and I can't copy the object with nodes or manually copy the nodes. Can anyone tell me how to copy the object with nodes and other properties? Or copy the object to another blend file with all of it's modifiers and stuffs. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I'd like to know how to merge blend files too.

Comment: It appears you can use Append and Link to do this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jIJ5n21J3EY

Comment: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Data_System/Linked_Libraries

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming you are talking about material nodes etc. If you *append* the object into the new file, it will bring over anything attached to it automatically such as materials and any node setups associated with it. Use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> or go to *File > Append* and navigate into the blend file as you would a folder, open the *Object* folder and select the object that you want to copy.

[image]

See [How can I reuse existing materials, objects, etc from an existing .blend?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81/how-can-i-reuse-existing-materials-objects-etc-from-an-existing-blend) for more info.

---

Alternatively, a much faster and easier way is to just copy paste the object directly into the new file by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> *(Copy selection to buffer)* and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> *(Paste selection from buffer)*. This will also bring over anything associated with the object.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for a quick reply. I am sorry that it's my mistake that the item is not containing nodes but the scene is containing nodes. Can you tell me how to copy the scene with the nodes?

Comment: @JimmyJommy Sorry I didn't see this. I'm busy at the moment but will post an update as soon as I can.