# How to render a scene with Cycles render and blender internal

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine

My problem is that I have made a in Blender render a plane with grass texture and I have made some rocks in a separate blender file with Cycles render. The problem is that when I do BR then it renders only the plane and the rocks are plain grey and when I do CR then the plane is grey but the rocks are looking good. Hopefully somebody can help me quick how to solve this issue

The video I used to do the rocks:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xRDFMYfsIcU

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking.. You have to set up materials for the render engine you want to use. Or are you asking how to combine BI renders with Cycles renders?

Comment: Sorry if the question is not to the point I'm a bit confused. Yes I would like to combine the Bl and Cycles renders

Comment: Here's an [example file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/30008) you can play with.

Comment: Thank you very much this is interesting.

One more thing, I would like to ask for your advice. How much time do you think I would need to put these on the same scene. Only the tree is a bigger file with 17 mb-s

[Woodland path](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/30009)
[Realistic rocks](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/30010)
[Skydome](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/30011)
[Animated tree](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/30012)

Comment: Oh and I totaly forgot the wolf(really beginner work) would need to go there too
[Wolf](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/30014) 5.57mb

Comment: Well, it's not too hard to put objects from one file into another. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/81/599. I would first pick a file to put all the other objects into (or create a new file), then create two scenes (one for BI and one for cycles). Then append/link/paste each object into it's appropriate scene in the destination file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you get gray a plane or rocks, is that materials are different in BI and Cycles, so to use, let's say Cycles, you have to "port" your materials (basicly remake them, with the tools availiable in the render engine); Since materials are different, when you switch between the renderers it applys a default materail to objects that don't have a propper one; That material just so happens to be gray. 
So I don't think it's possible to mix them, without using the compositor and transparency.

Comment: It is probably a duplicate question then, I didn't know what to enter into search since I just discovered the effects of Bl and Cycles renders today when I tried to combine two separate files that I need for a university project. Thank you for the link that clears it up somewhat, shame that I have no time to do it since my deadline is tomorrow