# How to model separate parts and re-use them?

Tags: modeling, objects, workflow

I am a new user and trying to determine if Blender can perform the 3D tasks I need for my projects.  I have 4 years experience with other 3D systems.

The questions are:

- In creating complex models with many unique parts (2000 part transmission), can separate parts be modeled and then joined to the main part? (Housings, gears, shafts, tubes, etc.)?
- Where common parts are used repeatably, can those parts be modeled and saved in a Resource folder?

Comment: Yes, it can do all of that.

Comment: If you want details on how to do any of those tasks, it will need to be in a separate question

Comment: This would be a good question to ask on http://blenderartists.org/.

Comment: I think about every 3d package allows the user to create a more complex model in incremements. For discussion oriented questions, it's best if you ask on the BA forums or in our chat. And yes, you can reuse models , see this question [How can I reuse existing materials, objects, etc from an existing .blend?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81/how-can-i-reuse-existing-materials-objects-etc-from-an-existing-blend). _(This technique is sometimes referred to as 'kit-bashing')_

Answer (score 4):

You can store and re-use parts. Just save the re-usable part in a separate file. Then, whenever you want to use it, push <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, navigate to the .blend file with the part in it, open it, select the objects folder, and select your object. It will then import that object and all its data into your scene. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

As a previous answer suggested you can import external objects or append objects from other blend files (*File* > *Append* or *File* > *Import*). Once imported / appended, you can join them to an existing object by selecting the objects you want to join and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>.