# how do i save my selfmade favorit color ramp gradient in node editor?

Tags: node-editor

[image]

i have created some cool favorite color gradients in the node editor.
 i want to save all of these so i can use them again later , also for use in other projects , but where is the save button ?
 on the picture you can see the gradient color , but there is no save button near around it .
how do i do this ?

to be more specific , in one project i want to be able to choose from hundreds of cool gradients that i have created in blender and have saved these , for later use. 
so when i work on a project and i don't like a gradient that i have used , i can go to a list where i have saved my selfmade gradients , and just pick out 1 of them , and than check out a next one , until i find one that i like. just about the same idea how you would do with choosing a right jpg for your texture, you have a folder somewhere , where you saved all your favourite jpgs , where you can choose from and check out which one fits best to your object. image now you can only choose from one JPG texture,  or in the worst case you need to hustle around a lot to try to import a second jpg etc etc .  that is how i feel now with the gradient question . there should be a save and load button somewhere to enjoy working with gradients on your object , just like you would enjoy cool JPG textures on your object. it seems no problem to choose from thousands of cool jpgs. just by one click , and keep going searching until you find your best one that fits here on your object.  if i can't save my cool self made gradients , i have no other choice then wait for an update for this , hopefully soon , maybe did i miss here something , but i have seen no option to load and save cool selfmade gradients. anyone ?

this question has been marked as a double, but it is different in my opinion. 
Can I make a custom node from a group and have that available in other projects?
that was the other question that has been compared to my question. it is different , because i am not asking for a node combination to save it and use it elsewhere. 
my question is how to save a specific part inside the node it self. how to save a favorite selfmade gradient collor ramp. and have these gradients saved in a folder with maybe 50 other different color combinations. that is not the same like how to make a custom node from a group.  because i don't want to make a new node for every color change that i wil make. so there is the difference. so far i only see answer where i can change my gradient when i create new nodes , but this is not gonna be a good solution .  imagine you have to create a new node for every jpg texture that you will import ? i mean in a situation when you scroll through your list ofjpgs and want to test all of them to pick out the best texture. it is easy and quick , with just a click , and the same workaround should be for changing a rollorramp, and go through your list of gradients , where you can choose your favourites to see if it fits your object in your project.  that is not the same thing as creating custom nodes to use in other projects question . 
blender has been around for a long time now , it should be there. it is so standard for an app working with gradients.

i am afraid blender is still in the stoneage regards to some specific simple basic functions that should be already updated long time ago . 
lets just hope, it will happen someday. 
but if i missed something , and someone can point me to an answer i would be happy to hear it .

i am not looking for a complete node combination export , like the other question. and than re-use ,  for each tiny color change that i make,

i need to create a list in a folder next to my jpg texture folders, where i can keep all my favorite gradient colorramp patches and choose them as easy as i choose a new jpg texture.

i guess the answer is No , but it should be yes . anyone agree ?

Comment: I do not think it is possible to save custom node settings as of yet, although this could theoretically be implemented in future.

Comment: but i can't believe this , such a simple thing like creating hundreds of cool gradients , and no way to save it ? 
actually i know how to do this the long way, i found a workaround for myself , i just save this whole project , with that specific cool gradient color combination that i created.
 if i need that gradient again i will go to that project and grab it from there.

Comment: but come on , you know this is way too much work fo such a simple task , also i don't have a chance to see the exact color when i search for the right fie that i saved long time ago. the blender file doesnt tell you the gradient color that you used , you need to open it and see it.

Comment: quickly change textures is cool by replacing them with one button . 

same should be for replacing and searching your favorite gradient. 

if not possible , lets hope the blender designers see this message and think about it .

for now , i will just keep doing the long way . but it is not right...

Comment: i didn't see a save button and i had a bad feeling about it , and was already worried for this ...sorry to hear it is not possible. but it should be !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how often you want to use your gradients, you can save them in two ways.

Both methods start by grouping your *ColorRamp* node. After you have set the gradient as you want, select the color ramp node and press <kbd>Crtl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> that will create a node group only containing the color ramp node. Rename the new node group, in the properties region <kbd>N</kbd> so you can find the gradient later.
[image: cycles node group settings]
[image: cycles node group]

If you use the gradients a lot, just save the node groups in your start up file.

The second method is to have a file of node assets, and when you want a gradient [Append](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/81/2217) the node group from the file, with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>.