# How to put a Part of my Model into a New File

Tags: modeling

I'm Newbie and i have a packet of Trees which are packed into one single 3ds file. How can i make seperate models of it? In Photoshop etc, i'd use "Copy&Paste" it into a new File, how is it done in blender, the easiest way?
[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can save the models in blend file and append them in a new file whenever you want using "File -> Append" (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>)

Comment: Id didnt work!!

Comment: Here is more detailed answer http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81/how-can-i-reuse-existing-materials-objects-etc-from-an-existing-blend

Comment: OMG! yes it did :o http://prntscr.com/6gd9uv please.. have a look :D How bad is this? :D:D

Comment: yes you can do it this way also, but its easier to append or link objects, materials or other data from your library blend files.