# Walk animation missing

Tags: animation

I've been trying to create some animations for a creature. I've created a walk animation for a creature already and right after I created an attack animation. However, the walk animation is gone somehow. I can't even find it when I search for it in action browser.

Could you please tell me where it might have gone?

Comment: Here' s the .blend file: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/37646
Don' t mind the weird animation. I have no idea how did that happen.
The smoke domain box ruined it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this has not changed in the latest versions an action will be deleted when it is not used (referenced) in the NLA-editor. You can keep currently unused action by adding a fake user (reference) with the 'F' button.

[image]

Comment: Oh. Thanks. Fortunately I saved the animations in different .blend files. Is it possible to import the walk cycle animation from one .blend file to other .blend file?

Comment: @TheLast_BlenderBender In the menu pick File/Append select the .blend and navigate to Action . Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81/how-can-i-reuse-existing-materials-objects-etc-from-an-existing-blend/83#83