# Uv map of appended object

Tags: uv

Let us say I have uv unwrapped an object and changed the uv map. Now when I append this object in another blend file, how can I obtain the changed uv map too. Because I think when I unwrap the appended object I get the "original" uv map

Comment: If you want both UV maps to be modified when you change the original, then it sounds like you are looking for [*Linking*](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/81/599)

Comment: If you append (not link) an UV unwrapped object, the appended (ie: imported) has also the "original" UVmap... it is an identical but separate copy of the whole object. linking is different, if you wish to maintain the relation with the "original" in the new file, as @gandalf3 said above.

Comment: .What I want is .... When I change the original uv map and I append (or link) the object I want to have the changed uv map .... And I don't want to have the original uv map. Is this done by linking and not by appending the object ? Because I want my image textures fitting the changed uv map

Answer (score 0):

Try linking the object, duplicate it, delete the linked object. The duplicated object has the uv maps of the original, but you can now modify them.