# Reuse materials in blender cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

I make environments in blender and I often have to create a new material for every single object I have in my scene. Having to make all the nodes over and over again takes much time and it's a pain.
So, my question is if there is a way to create a material and make other objects inherit from it, like unreal engine, so I have only to change the textures in the nodes, and don't have to create the nodes all over again.

Comment: The question linked above references the compositor, but the exact same principles are true for materials.

Comment: Also related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81/how-can-i-reuse-existing-materials-objects-etc-from-an-existing-blend