# Is there a library of components for modelling buildings?

Tags: modeling

I am about to embark upon learning Blender to product 3D models of a building project. Before I start, is there a library of components for modelling buildings?

Comment: archimesh addon https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fxIoDvJHl3Q

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Blender resources for architects?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7657/blender-resources-for-architects)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a library in Blender 2.76?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56654/is-there-a-library-in-blender-2-76)

Answer (score 2):

Not inside of Blender there is not, Most assets like that you have to download yourself, However there are a few in File> User preferences > Addons > mesh
Enable them all and try them out, see if you get what you want. Also There are free models at http://tf3dm.com/