# What is a best way to organize my own kitbash library?

Tags: add-on, blend-files, linked-data

I do have assets that I made over the years, and when I need them, I link or append them 'norma' Blender way. However while the list of assets grows it is becoming more and more cumbersome.

There is this awesome [kitbash addon](https://blendermarket.com/products/kit-ops-pro-asset--kitbashing-addon), but as my models are more organic, I do not think it is the right tool for the job.

How would you organize your collection of assets to be more productive in your designs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an ongoing project for future Blender 2.8X called [Asset Engine](https://code.blender.org/2016/10/asset-management-and-pipeline/) to improve the asset and library management features of Blender.

It will feature local file system based storage of assets with tagging and organization features, and previewing capabilities as stated in the [Wiki](https://en.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.8/Source/Assets_and_Static_Overrides/Roadmap_October_2017).

It is unknown at this point when it will be ready and integrated into official releases, however it is unlikely to make it into the first official 2.80 release.

At the moment you can currently organize your assets as group instances or even individual  objects and [generate datablock preview images](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56654/is-there-a-library-in-blender-2-76/56676#56676) for them. You can then browse the assets using Blender's built in file browser with thumbnail previewing capabilities-