# How do you save a model as a file?

Tags: modeling

I use Pokémon models from a website. I animate them, by putting bones in them. but I don't want to put bones into a model every time I make a new scene to animate. I download the models from a website, how do I save my own models as files so i can import them?

Comment: What you are propably looking for is "linking" or "appending". Both techniques allow you to save items (can be mesh, armatures, materials, everything, and any combination of it) in one file, and then re-use them in another. Appending is more easy to use for beginners, as it is like an Import function, but reading the data directly from another blend file. Linking however will only create a reference to the other file, and update it every time you load the child scene / file. So for example, one file holds the character with the bones, the other file(s) the animation.

Comment: Possibly Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81/how-can-i-reuse-existing-materials-objects-etc-from-an-existing-blend

Answer (score 2):

Blender does not have separate file formats for scenes, models, materials, etc.
Everything - even textures, if you pack them - is in the blend file. This is a big advantage since you can easily build libraries with blend files, then link or append (create a copy) your models into a new scene.

The only way to save models is to export them into one of the model formats that Blender offers. This could be .obj for static models or .fbx when they are fully rigged.

One thing you should keep in mind is that you select your model before exporting and then check the option to export only the selected model.

[image: export selected in fbx exporter]