# Need Help making a frosted light Bulb material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, transparency, glass

I been trying to make a material that looks like this:

[image]

I have only been able to make this:

[image]

I would love to have some help with this.

Comment: In my opinion you don't need the transparent but a subsurface scattering one. Also, having an emission shader as part of the surface kills all of the shading and reflections. In your reference image the light bulb seems to be completely off and is lit by outside sources. Think of the qualities of your object: the surface has some transparency but there is nothing on the scene that is shown through it. Same with reflections, glass is reflective, but since the rest of the scene is empty (or has a completely homogeneous color), there is nothing to reflect on the surface of the light bulb.

Answer (score 1):

### Overview:

[image: Final]

I'll show you two methods with their pros and cons. One of them are using [Cynicat Pro PBR Nodes](https://gumroad.com/cynicatpro) and the second one is created by myself. As pointed by @cegeton you'll need some kind of environment to see reflections in light bulb. Try HDRI maps.

Both setups are using same masking method so I'll start with that.

### Mask:

Mask is for the transition between clear glass and frosted/milky one.

[image: Mask]

You can control position of this transition and sharpness/smoothness.

### My method:

My setup is using simple mix of **Translucent** and **Glossy** shader by **Layer Weight**.

If you want to have less/more reflection you can tweak **Layer Weight Blend** value.

**Pros:** It's good if you want to have it completely off (no light emission) and also works with light source inside.

**Cons:** It's pretty "heavy" to render, note amount of noise in final render.

[image: mine]

### Method based on Cynicat Pro PBR:

After downloading file from link in overview, [append](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81/how-can-i-reuse-existing-materials-objects-etc-from-an-existing-blend) from it two **Materials - Light and Glass**. Then set **Light** as your object material and modify it accordingly to the image. PBR nodes are in **Add** > **Group** in **Node Editor**.

**Pros:** It look awesome. It's really fast. It's easy to manipulate.

**Cons:** It need to be always turned on. **Emission** value should be higher then something around 0.2, otherwise material is black.

[image: OBR]