# Can a cycles material input a texture from outside of the material?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, vertex-colors

I'm creating a Blender cycles material that combines a mesh's vertex colors with a texture.

I use the Attribute node to get the vertex colors, and the Image Texture node to get the texture:

[image: Cycles nodes]

I want to link this material to other Blender files. When I do this, the nodes become unchangeable. **I don't want to make the material local if possible.**

[image: Linked cycles nodes]

For the vertex colors attribute, it still works; whatever the mesh's vertex colors are will show up correctly.

For the texture, I simply cannot add a texture as the options are disabled.

Is there a way I can set a texture on the mesh that the linked material will read as input (or some other way to "plug-in" any texture to the linked material) rather than have a specific texture be a part of the material itself?

Comment: Group material nodes except for the texture and plug texture in the end file. Related - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81/how-can-i-reuse-existing-materials-objects-etc-from-an-existing-blend

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to plug the texture in the end file? In the end file the nodes are all locked of the linked material, so I can't attach anything to the node that receives the Image Texture currently, unless I make the material local.

Comment: I meant not linking material rather than linking node group and adding that into the material. So yes, material will be actually local in the end file. There will be image texture node (local) with texture, then linked node group and then material output. Other than that there indeed might be no other way

Comment: I understand now. It's a little inconvenient, but it works well enough. Thanks!